# Why do I get Error when calling library (rdd)

Tags: r, rdd

I have installed the rdd package, when calling `library(rdd)`, I get error  an message:

> Error: package ‘car’ required by ‘AER’ could not be found"

I have used functions from car (like anova) so I know I have it.

I have MAC OS 10.15.1, R 3.6.1 , I reinstalled R and RStudio.

```
install.packages("rdd")
library(rdd)
```

> Loading required package: AER
>
> Error: package ‘car’ required by ‘AER’ could not be found

Comment: Are you sure the car package is installed? Try installing it again.

Answer (score 1):

Packages may have dependencies (i.e. other packages) and those dependent package may have dependencies of their very own. Appears that rdd requires AER which in turn requires car. So you need all three (and possibly even more). At the very least you need to now install pkg:car.

(I know this may seem a duplicate but I'm not sure the usual duplicate nominees have seen a multi-level dependency situation such as this. )

Suggest you execute both of this lines:

```
install.packages("AER", dependencies=TRUE) # should pick up car
# maybe also need install.packages("car", dependencies=TRUE) 
install.packages("rdd", dependencies=TRUE)
```

If you get further errors, pay attention to the *first* error message and use install package recursively until you establish a full set of dependencies and dependencies of dependencies.